# Latex: Space remove between parboxes

Tags: latex, tikz

I try to remove the vertical space between the textboxes. However, since I use the newcommand that opens a new tikzpicture each time, I cannot use setspace I think?
Any other ideas?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=15mm, top=10mm, footskip=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\xdefinecolor{links}{RGB}{251,212,180}
\xdefinecolor{rechts}{RGB}{214,227,188}
\xdefinecolor{mitte}{RGB}{218,216,215}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{sms} = [rectangle callout, draw,very thick, rounded corners, minimum height=20pt]

\newcommand{\smsr}[1]{\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [sms, align=right,callout relative pointer={(0.5,0)}, fill=rechts] {\begin{varwidth}{0.7\textwidth}{#1}\end{varwidth}};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{flushright}} 

\newcommand{\smsl}[1]{\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \node[sms, align=left,callout relative pointer={(-0.5,0)},  fill=links] {\begin{varwidth}{0.7\textwidth}{#1}\end{varwidth}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\end{flushleft}    } 

\newcommand{\datum}[1]{\begin{center}   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, very thick, text width=0.4\textwidth, rounded corners, draw,align=center, fill=mitte] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture} \end{center}} 


\begin{document}
\small

\datum{Saturday, 22.July}
\smsl{Send Hallo}
\smsr{Answer Bye. Very long line to show the function of automatic line-breaking.}
\smsr{Still awake?}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting each `tikzpicture` inside another environment may insert unwanted vertical spacing. Perhaps don't use them:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=10mm, right=10mm, bottom=15mm, top=10mm, footskip=5mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor} 
\xdefinecolor{links}{RGB}{251,212,180}
\xdefinecolor{rechts}{RGB}{214,227,188}
\xdefinecolor{mitte}{RGB}{218,216,215}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\tikzstyle{sms} = [rectangle callout, draw,very thick, rounded corners, minimum height=20pt]

\newcommand{\smsr}[1]{\hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [sms, align=right,callout relative pointer={(0.5,0)}, fill=rechts] {\begin{varwidth}{0.7\textwidth}{#1}\end{varwidth}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par}

\newcommand{\smsl}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[sms, align=left,callout relative pointer={(-0.5,0)},  fill=links] {\begin{varwidth}{0.7\textwidth}{#1}\end{varwidth}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \par}

\newcommand{\datum}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[rectangle, very thick, text width=0.4\textwidth, rounded corners, draw,align=center, fill=mitte] {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\small

\datum{Saturday, 22 July}
\smsl{Send Hallo}
\smsr{Answer Bye. Very long line to show the function of automatic line-breaking.}
\smsr{Still awake?}

\end{document}
```

I also removed any paragraph indent, but kept the title set with some distance between the following text bubbles (using `center`).

An alternative to the above, if you plan on using `\smsl`, `\smsr` and `\datum` for *everything*, would be to use `\raggedright`, `\raggedleft` and `\centering` respectively (rather than `\hfill` for `\smsl` and `center` for `datum`).